# ComboBox as a cell in TreeGrid of Ext-GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to render ComboBox for in a cell of all leaf nodes in TreeGrid.can any one help me regarding this ? .Im not able to figure it out .

Thanks,
Bhaswanth Gattineni .

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples in Sencha overivew.

Treegrid with button example
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#widgetrenderertreegrid

Replace button widget with combobox, in renderer check if node is a leafnode;

```
 ColumnConfig name = new ColumnConfig("name", "Name", 100);  
    name.setRenderer(new WidgetTreeGridCellRenderer<ModelData>(){  
      @Override  
      public Widget getWidget(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,  
          ListStore<ModelData> store, Grid<ModelData> grid) {  
        final SimpleComboBox<String> combo = new SimpleComboBox<String>();  
         combo.setForceSelection(true);  
         combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);  
         combo.add("aaaaa");    
         return combo;
     }  
    });
```

Treegrid with textfield example

http://www.sencha.com/examples/#roweditortreegrid